# How to get powershell IIS Instance and associated certificate thumbprints

Tags: powershell, iis, certificate, windows-server-2012

I am trying to list all the IIS sites and their associated certificate thumb prints.

I really just want it like

IIS Site, Thumbprint.

Seems simple enough, but I can't for the life of me get this to work. (note I want the actaull IIS site, not the friendly name or certificate subject)

I can get them individually, but how do I join it to show both.

```
$sites = Get-Website | ? { $_.State -eq "Started" } | % { $_.Name }
$certs = Get-ChildItem IIS:SSLBindings | ? {
           $sites -contains $_.Sites.Value
         } | % { $_.Thumbprint }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    $certs = Get-ChildItem IIS:SSLBindings

    Get-Website | 
        Where-Object State -eq "Started" |
            ForEach-Object {
                $siteName = $_.Name
                [PsCustomObject]@{
                    Site=$siteName
                    CertThumb=($certs | Where-Object {$_.Sites.value -contains $siteName}).Thumbprint
                }
            }
```